# Backup of azure storage account file share

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have quite a few shared files in an azure file share, what is the best backup method for these?
This is in case a user deletes a file and I need to recover, I understand that the files on azure storage are written across multiple disks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real answer to this, you can use any backup solution\technic you desire.
As for the Azure side, Azure does provide a way to do this, but for blobs only. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob/

edit: As Gaurav pointed out, you could async copy the Azure Files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#file-copy

Comment: Azure Files also support async copy like blobs. One could copy files from a share to another share (within or a different storage account) or to a blob container (again within or a different storage account). Request you to update your answer.

Comment: could you provide a link?

Comment: Using AzCopy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#file-copy. HTH.